# JavaScript date coming up 5 hours short

Tags: javascript

I'm making a JavaScript mkDate function like what PHP has and I've gotten it to come out with the right date but it's 5 hours short of what it's supposed to be. I've been staring at this for like an hour. Here is my code:

```
function mkDate(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)
{
    month--;

    var monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    if(new Date(year, 1, 29, 0, 0).getMonth() != 2) { monthDays[1] = 29; }

    var years = year - 1970;
    var leapYears = parseInt((year - 1972)/4);

    var days = (years - leapYears) * 365;
    days += leapYears * 366;

    for(var i = 0; i < month; i++) {
            days += monthDays[i];
    }

    days += day;

    var time = days * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
    time += hour * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    time += minute * 60 * 1000;
    time += second * 1000;

    var tDate = new Date();
    tDate.setTime(time);
    return tDate;
}

var myDate = mkDate(16, 38, 23, 7, 10, 2013);

// myDate should be Wednesday, July 10, 2013 04:38:23 PM
// but myDate is coming up with Wednesday, July 10, 2013 11:38:23 AM
```

Comment: Timezone issues?

Comment: No I'm testing this on my local computer, its CDT

Comment: Do you have to do this yourself?  Your leap-year detection is not fully correct, for a start.

Comment: When I do this I get `Wed Jul 10 2013 17:38:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` which is what you wanted (considering my timezone)

Comment: Your local computer has a time zone, too.  :-)

Comment: Look at moment.js for anything Date related. It is really awesome will save you plenty of precious development time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Time zone issue: [settime takes milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC as an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime), and you feed it a local time.  You are in CDT, which is 5 hours west of UTC.

Now, [Date has a constructor which takes exactly the fields you're feeding mkDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (but in another order), so your function can be reduced to

```
function mkDate(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)
{
    return new Date(year,month-1,day,hour, minute, second);
}
```

and that Date will be in local time.

edit: I missed the subtraction of 1 on the month field - at least one misfeature shared by Java and Javascript....

Comment: Oh, ok so I guess it was right. I didn't know that it was set in UTC. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [*Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)'s own constructor for this, possibly with [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) if your input is expected to be a *UTC* time. This means native functions do all the work for you.

```
function mkDate(hour, minute, second, month, day, year) {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute));
}

mkDate(16, 38, 23, 7, 10, 2013);
// Wed Jul 10 2013 17:38:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Remember a *Date* is displayed in your local time by default, if you want to see it in *UTC/GMT* use [`Date.prototype.toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) or [`Date.prototype.toGMTString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString)